# How to Re-Direct non WWW, non HTTPS to WWW, HTTPS without Multiple Re-Directs?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, https

I hope you can help with this htaccess issue please? I basically have the htaccess rules working apart from in one scenario. This is the case where a user visits the site on a non HTTPS and non WWW links.

**Re-Directs**

1. User visits on http/non-WWW URL
2. User is redirected initially to the http/WWW URL
3. User is then redirected to https://www.website

You can see the behaviour here:

http://childrens-curtains.co.uk

All other scenarios work fine.

I want to try to remove the 2nd redirect from the sequence so it behaves like this:

User visits on http and is immediately redirected to the https/www version without the 2nd step (if that makes sense?)

The current scenario causes multiple re-directs, which I understand is a bad approach from an SEO perspective.

This is my htaccess redirect rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
# This will enable the Rewrite capabilities

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
# This checks to make sure the connection is not already HTTPS

RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [L,R=301]
# This rule will redirect users from their original location, to the same location but using HTTPS.
# The leading slash is made optional so that this will work either in httpd.conf
# or .htaccess context
```

Comment: There is no rule shown here adding `www` and keeping `http` URL. Do you have some rule in Apache config also?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code keepin into .htaccess file.

To add www add following code.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^**domainname**\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domainname\.com$
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ "http\:\/\/www\.domainname\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

To add http add following code.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domainname.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domainname.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Which will add both http as well as www to URL.

Thanks.